# Conditional Coin Probability:Will The Decision Change

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

A decision making problem will be resolved by tossing $2n + 1$ coins. If Head comes in majority one option will be taken, for majority of tails it’ll be the other one. Initially all the coins were fair. A witty mathematician replaced $n$ pairs of fair coins with $n$ pairs of biased coins, but in each pair the probability of obtaining head in one is the same the probability of obtaining tail in the other. Will this cause any favor for any of the options available? Justify with logic

Answer (score 2):

No. Because the situation is symmetric. Switching the 'labels' Head and Tail has no consequences here.